# How to permit custom params using strong parametes gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, strong-parameters

I am getting params as follows.

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"auth_token=", "js_data_entry"=>[{"data_entry"=>[{"name"=>"test_book22", "node_id"=>"65", "field_type"=>"Text", "options_attributes"=>[{"option_value"=>""}], "location"=>"Body", "rank"=>"", "must_fill"=>"0", "multi"=>"0", "role"=>["4"], "update_db"=>"vocation.name", "select_db"=>""}], "js_editor"=>[{"field_id"=>"", "field_class"=>"", "js_code"=>""}]}], "node_id"=>"65", "commit"=>"Submit", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"data_entries"}
```

I tried to permit params as follows

```
 def entry_params
   params.require(:js_data_entry).permit([:node_id, :field_type, :name, :location, :rank, :multi, :must_fill, :update_db, :select_db, :role, :options_attributes])
 end
```

but it's throwing

```
undefined method `permit' for #<Array:0xc603e78>
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Rails3 with strong-parameters gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue as follows..

```
 params.require(:js_data_entry)[0].permit(:data_entry=>[:node_id, :field_type, :name, :location, :rank, :multi, :must_fill, :update_db, :select_db, :role=>[], :options_attributes=>[:option_value]], :js_editor=>[:field_id,:field_class,:js_code])
```